# Python: File pointers

Tags: python-3.4

I am developing some tool by make use of python 3.4.2 shell. But i stopped while dealing with file pointers in python. Basically what i am doing is merging the file with another file. I came across scenario, wherein i will search for a string in the file, the other file content i need to merge should start from that string. So please could anyone suggest me on this??

- How to move reversely in a file using python file commands?
- i tried using seek() and tell() but didn't workout.
- can i use seek(-5,1) to go back 5 bytes back and write from that position?All answers are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share the code you wrote so far. SO is not writing service. Information on file operations can be found in https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: Hey, i referred that URL which u sent that issue got resolved. Thanks for ur time....But i raised with one more issue....application which i developed is showing "not responding" but results are getting correctly.

Comment: Hey guys,  Recently i have done with my python program using tkinter GUI which performs some sort of automation. I wanted to convert this python program to runnable .exe on windows. i did it using cx_freeze software. But the problem araised is after generating exe, if i click it one pop-up window (may be command window) will come and disappears suddenly. So requesing you people to provide resolution...All answers are appreciated. Thanks in advance.....